# Connectivity between nano nodes created by docker-compose

Tags: git, docker, docker-compose

I am currently doing some testing on the test_network (I followed the [build instructions](https://github.com/nanocurrency/raiblocks/wiki/Build-rai_node-samples) for Ubuntu 16.04 and changed the CMake variable `cmake -DACTIVE_NETWORK=rai_test_network` ). I did this using Docker

```
 Client:
  Version:       18.03.0-ce
  API version:   1.37
  Go version:    go1.9.2
  Git commit:    0520e24
  Built: Wed Mar 21 23:05:52 2018
  OS/Arch:       linux/amd64
  Experimental:  false
  Orchestrator:  swarm
Server:
  Engine:
  Version:      18.03.0-ce
  API version:  1.37 (minimum version 1.12) 
  Go version:   go1.9.4
  Git commit:   0520e24
  Built:        Wed Mar 21 23:14:54 2018
  OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
  Experimental: false `
```

I commit an image `docker commit <CONTAINER_ID> <IMAGE:TAG>` and I would like to create my network using `docker-compose` built on that image. I create two services named peer1 and peer2, run `./rai_node --daemon` in each one of them, then I obtain a directory RaiBlocksTest in the same directory where I cloned the [nano github repository](http://github.com/nanocurrency/raiblocks.git) and it contains a `config.json` file.

I change

```
"rpc_enable": "true", 
"rpc": {
    "address": "::ffff:127.0.0.1",
    "port": "7076",
    "enable_control": "true",
    "frontier_request_limit": "16384",
    "chain_request_limit": "16384"
},
"node": {
    "version": "13",
    "peering_port": "54000",
    "bootstrap_fraction_numerator": "1",
    "receive_minimum": "10",
    "logging": {
        "version": "4",
        "ledger": "true"
    "work_peers": "",
    "preconfigured_peers": ["::ffff:172.20.0.2" , "::ffff:172.20.0.3"],
    "preconfigured_representatives": "",
    "online_weight_minimum": "60",
    "online_weight_quorum": "50",
    "password_fanout": "1024",
    "io_threads": "4",
    "work_threads": "4",
    "enable_voting": "false",
    "bootstrap_connections": "4",
    "bootstrap_connections_max": "64",
    "callback_address": "",
    "callback_port": "0",
    "callback_target": "",
    "lmdb_max_dbs": "128"
},
```

The nodes of the docker-compose network can  ping each other, but the Nano nodes cannot see each other: when running the RPC command

```
{ 
   "action" :  "peers" 
}
```

The answer is

```
{ 
   "peers" : "" 
}
```

Has anyone encountered this problem or know how to deal with it? I would really appreciate any help. Thank's a lot! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I passed this problem by changing all vlaues `"false"` to `"true"`. I also changed the ip address `::ffff:127.0.0.1` to `::ffff:0.0.0.0` so that I can send RPC commands from other containers in the docker-compose network I created. Problem solved